# Unidentified PHP Framework or CMS - with folders adr, arc, cal, cms, frm, mdb, mobile, sys

Tags: php, frameworks, content-management-system

I have a website that I am engaged by my boss to maintain and update accordingly. It has a completely strange framework or CMS. The folder structure is like this:

```
-folder inform(with subfolders named "adr", "arc", "cal", "cms", "frm", "mdb",  "mobile", and "sys")
-folder media
-folder web (with subfolders pix - with some gif files inside it, scripts - with javascript files in it, styles - with css files in it);
```

other files inside root directory. These other files have strange names, like `breeder.php?start=6&id=21.html` and `2012.php-id=163&year=0.html`

Does anyone have an idea which CMS is this, or which framework? So that I can learn it and start using it on this website

Comment: It is going to be incredibly difficult to identify the CMS or framework based on what you have provided so far. if you could provide a list of all directories and files it would go a long way to assisting in identifying the framework being used.

Comment: @Vladimir Despotovic: does the project have any documentation? Maybe some comments in a index.php file? Nothing provided tells me your project is an 'official' CMS. Looks like a custom built solution.

Comment: I listed every single file and directory in the web site. I will try and find some docs inside files, but I was looking for it and I couldn't find any. If I find something Ill surely post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure it is an unknown framework, ie. a custom made web site.